# AWK summary file from a filtered list

Tags: awk, grep

I have 2 files, the first being a file of records that tell me which rows from the second file I am interested in (I'll call this the FILTER_FILE).
This file can contain duplicate lines and I only need to process the second file for each unique line in the first.
The second file (lets call it the DATA_FILE) contains multiple lines for each line in file 1 and has a number that needs to be summed for the first 3 occurrences of each match from the first file (the others can be discarded).

I've tried a few things but my knowledge of `awk` is basic though I am using it as much as I can to try to pick it up.

This is the rather clumsy attempt that I tried:

```
awk '{print $1 " " $2}' filter_file | sort -u >> tst
```

---

```
while read filter; 
    do grep "$filter" data_file | head -3; done < tst >> ./short_data_file
```

---

```
while read line;
    do grep "$filter" short_data_file | awk '{ sum += $3 } END { print $1 " " $2 " " sum }' ; done < tst >> summary_file
```

Filter file example format:

```
abcd 123456  
abcd 123456  
abcd 123456  
abcd 123457  
abcd 234567  
abcd 234567  
abcd 234567  
abcd 890123  
abcd 890123  
abcd 890123  
abcd 890123  
abcd 890123  
abde 344566  
abde 344566  
abde 344566
```

Data file example format:

```
abcd 123456 3  
abcd 123456 4  
abcd 123456 3  
abcd 123456 56  
abcd 123456 6   
abcd 123456 1   
abcd 123457 6  
abcd 123457 4  
abcd 123457 89  
abcd 123457 3  
abcd 123457 9  
abcd 234567 5  
abcd 234567 3  
abcd 234567 8   
abcd 234567 6  
abcd 234567 76  
abcd 234567 34  
abcd 234567 0  
abcd 234567 7  
abcd 890123 5  
abde 344566 152
```

Edit: This is the output that would be generated by the above data files

```
abcd 123456 10  
abcd 123457 99  
abcd 234567 16  
abcd 890123 5  
abde 344566 152
```

Edit: The actual real data files will be large; thousands in the filter file and millions in the data.

Comment: I think your objective is not very clear from reading your post. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135430/display-only-the-nth-match-of-grep

Comment: You can also provide sample output expected, so that people can help better.

Comment: @Baazigar - Sorry, that post does not cover the problem. I've added an expected output and I hope that makes it clearer. Thanks for the input and any suggestions are welcome. It'd be nice to solve it myself !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
awk 'NR == FNR { data[$1 " " $2]=0 ; next ; }
{ if ($1 " " $2 in data) data[$1 " " $2]+=$3 }
 END { for ( d in data ) printf "%s %d\n",d,data[d] ;} ' filter data
```

(this can be in one line)

where

- `NR == FNR { data[$1 " " $2]=0 ; next ; }` store line from filter file
- `{ if ($1 " " $2 in data) data[$1 " " $2]+=$3 }` add value from third colum if in data

  - `END { for ( d in data ) printf "%s %d\n",d,data[d] ;}` print sum

note that output order is randomized, you may whish to pipe to `sort`.

## first 3 line

here is the modifed awk

```
NR == FNR { countit[$1 " " $2]=0 ; next ; }
{ if ($1 " " $2 in countit) {
    data[$1 " " $2]+=$3 ;
    countit[$1 " " $2] ++ ;
    if ( countit[$1 " " $2] == 3 ) {
            printf "%s %s %s\n",$1,$2,data[$1 " " $2] ;
            delete data[$1 " " $2] ;
            delete countit[$1 " " $2] ;
    }
    }
}

 END { for ( d in data ) printf "%s %d\n",d,data[d] ;}
```

depending on what to do with incomplete list (e.g. 1 or 2 element), you may delete END line.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try to make it so that the SUM only applies to the first three lines of data matching each filter line. Also, would I be right in thinking that this builds the data array up as it goes through the files and then prints it all out at the end ? Which MAY be an issue as the actual file of real values will be Gb in size.

Comment: my bad, I'll fix it tomorrow.

Comment: That is spot on. I have a lot to learn, clearly. Many thanks.